# Как проверять оплату через Qiwi в Python?

Tags: python, qiwi

Собственно, необходимо сделать проверку операций с определенными примечаниями (не электронные кассы, а по логину/паролю). Вроде как-то делают, но неясно как, ибо совсем нет по этому поводу информации

Answer (score 0):

Есть документация по официальному API QIWI кошелька https://developer.qiwi.com/qiwiwallet/qiwicom_ru.html
Там можно найти GET запросы на получение истории платежей.

В Python можно реализовать через import sessions.

Comment: Чем это поможет автору вопроса? Для аргументированного ответа недостаточно дать одну ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы посмотреть полностью методы, можно воспользоваться методами, но самое примечательное тут:

```
Пример 1. Последние 10 платежей

user@server:~$ curl "https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v1/persons/79112223344/payments?rows=10"
  --header "Accept: application/json" 
  --header "Content-Type: application/json"
  --header "Authorization: Bearer YUu2qw048gtdsvlk3iu"
```

У API QIWI достаточно просто сделана реализация данных методов, сам планирую подключить автопополнение сервиса Onlinesim через докуметацию

Comment: "чтобы посмотреть полностью методы, можно воспользоваться методами" - не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду?